# Split a parent class name and add to each child element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to figure out a way to split values from a parent classname and add each separate value to each child inside the parent (the number of child elements is variable).

There might be class names with one value or multiple values.

```
<div class="block-33-33-33-33">
  <div class="card block__col--33"></div>
  <div class="card block__col--33"></div>
  <div class="card block__col--33"></div>
  <div class="card block__col--33"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="block-50-50">
  <div class="card block__col--50"></div>
  <div class="card block__col--50"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="block-100">
  <div class="card block__col--100"></div>
</div>
```

What would the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: is the number of classname will always equal to the number of child elements?

Comment: Yes, correct. If there are 4 values, there will be 4 child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` like the following way:

```js
var pClass = document.querySelector('div[class^=block]').classList.value.split('-');
pClass.shift(); // remove the first item

document.querySelectorAll('div.card').forEach(function(el, i){
  el.classList.add('block__col--'+ pClass[i]);
});
```

```css
.block__col--33{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-33-33-33-33">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let parentDiv = $("body > div")
let parentClassArr = parentDiv.attr('class').split('-')
for (let i = 1; i < parentClassArr.length; i++) {
  parentDiv.children().eq(i - 1).addClass(parentClassArr[0] + '__col--' + parentClassArr[i])
  console.log(parentDiv.children().eq(i - 1).attr('class'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="block-33-33-33-33">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OP didn't tag or mention jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=block-]");
blocks.forEach(splitParentClassNameToChildren);

function splitParentClassNameToChildren(parent) {
    const { className } = parent;
  const splitValues = className.match(/(\d\d)/g);
  splitValues.forEach((value, i) => {
    parent.children[i].classList.add(`block__col--${value}`);
  })
}
```

In action => https://jsfiddle.net/moorthyrweb/z3jLqwn4/14/